# Not 'sourceType: module' error when testing Angular with Cypress in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I'm inside of an Angular 8 project with Cypress version 4.2.0 and getting the following error when trying to import `.ts` files

```
/.../cypress/integration/main.spec.ts:1
import { MOCK1, MOCK2, MOCK3 } from '../fixtures/mocks/index';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
        "types": ["cypress"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is required `sourceType": "module"`

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  }
}
```

Reference link https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint#configuration